# Manage SQL Server 2005 Enterprise using SQL Server 2005 Management Studio Express

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

Can I use Management Studio Express to do tasks like querying, backing up and shrinking db, on a SQL Server Enterprise 2005?

Comment: Yes. Try it and read the documentation - it is all there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are certain tasks you will not be able to do; for example, you cannot manage SQL Server Agent jobs, use the Import/Export wizard, run traces with SQL Server, or run some of the canned reports.

If the lowest version of SQL Server you have to manage is SQL Server 2005, I highly recommend abandoning the 2005 version of Management Studio Express and getting the most recent 2012 version. It is the first version of the Express Edition tools that actually supports all of the functionality instead of a subset. Download the latest version here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms

As an aside, you really should not be shrinking your database except in response to an abnormal event.

Comment: Hi, Frist of all Thanks for your respone and advice, I am shrinking the database because the Log file is now 28 GB, what do you advice?

Comment: @user1010572 either switching to simple recovery or backing up the log more often. You will have to perform a shrink once to get it back to normal, but using the right recovery model should prevent the need to do it regularly enough that you need a UI to assist you.

Comment: Its is actually Sharepoint database, I will switch it to Simple Recovery before shrinking, but I dont know if I can leave it like this after shrinking